# É possível utilizar o addEventListner dessa forma?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

Estou estudando javascript e decidi brincar um pouco com a criação de campos com o **DOM CORE**.

Este é o código que fiz até agora :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
<input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone">
<button id="submit">+</button>
<div class="n_campos"></div>

<script>

    document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        let n_telefone = document.createElement('label');
        let text = document.createTextNode('Telefone:');

        n_telefone.appendChild(text);

        let i_telefone = document.createElement('input');
        i_telefone.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        i_telefone.setAttribute('name', 'telefone');

        let buttonRemove = document.createElement('button');
        text = document.createTextNode('X');
        buttonRemove.appendChild(text);
        buttonRemove.setAttribute('id', 'remover');

        document.querySelector('.n_campos').appendChild(n_telefone);
        document.querySelector('.n_campos').appendChild(i_telefone);
        document.querySelector('.n_campos').appendChild(buttonRemove);   

    });

    document.querySelector('#remover').addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('removido');
    }); 

</script>
```

A criação de campos está funcionando normalmente, porém estou tentando remover o campo criado de uma forma que não sei se é possível. Como podem ver aqui :

```
let buttonRemove = document.createElement('button');
text = document.createTextNode('X');
buttonRemove.appendChild(text);
buttonRemove.setAttribute('id', 'remover');
```

Estou atribuindo um id *#remover* ao botão e quando ele for clicado é chamado outro **addEventListner** para remove-lo, porém bato de cara com 2 problemas primeiro quando chamo o **addEventListner** da forma que está abaixo, o id *#remover* ainda não foi criado e me é retornado que a propriedade não existe , ai quando adiciono um novo campo e agora existe o id *#remover*, ele não me printa no console o *"removido"*.

Eu sei que posso remover os campos, apenas setando o atributo **onclick** no botão e chamando uma função `buttonRemove.setAttribute('onclick', 'algumafuncao()')`, no entanto queria saber se é possível da forma que mencionei acima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pois, o problema é que estás a registar `document.querySelector('#remover').addEventListener('click',` antes dele existir.

O melhor seria juntares esse auscultador de evento no momento da criação do botão. Em vêz de

```
buttonRemove.setAttribute('id', 'remover');
```

usar

```
buttonRemove.addEventListener('click', ...
```

Assim tens a certeza que é o elemento certo e só registas o auscultador de evento uma vez.

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou.